# Converting null to 0 using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Quick question, I want to convert all instances of null values into 0 so I can perform a sum. How am I able to do this with SOAP UI groovy scripting?

Below is the code:

```
def resultSearchCostGroup = json.products.costGroups.costLines.search

if (resultSearchCostGroup == null)
resultSearchCostGroup = 0

int totalSearchCostGroup = json.products.costGroups.costLines.search.sum()
```

Latest code:

```
// Search - Cost group
def resultSearchCostGroup = json.products.costGroups.costLines.search.collect { it ?: 0 }.sum()
log.info resultSearchCostGroup
int totalSearchCostGroup = json.products.costGroups.costLines.search.collect { it ?: 0 }.sum()
log.info resultSearchCostGroup
```

Thank you

Comment: Why the javascript tag here?

Comment: @DenysSéguret think they meant json

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
json.products.costGroups.costLines.search.collectMany { it ?: 0 }.sum()
```

Comment: I receive this error: Cannot cast object '[[null, null], [null, null, null, null], [null, null]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'int'. I'll update the question with the latest code

Comment: Ah, didn't realise it was a list of lists, try collectMany. Updated answer

Comment: Hi Tim, will have to more likely test it tomorrow because our API is down now so I cannot import any json. I will give it a test tomorrow. Thank you very much.